# How do I pair questions and solutions together

Tags: macros, formatting, cross-referencing, packages

I have the following scenario.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
begin{flushleft}
\begin{questions}
\begin{parts}

\part[1] %Question 1
Write an algebraic expression for " a number plus 5".\lines{1}

\part[1] %Question 2
Write an algebraic expression for "a number minus 3".\lines{1}

Solutions

\textbf{[1]} $x+5$  % Solution to Question 1

\textbf{[2]} $x-3$  % Solution to Question 2

\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

How can I pair up each parts to their respective solution, eg 'Question 1 and Solution to Question 1' such that if I want to move (up or down) or delete \parts, so too will the solution move or delete.

So something like this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
begin{flushleft}
\begin{questions}
\begin{parts}

\part[1] %Question 2        % I have just moved Question 2 above Quesiton 1
Write an algebraic expression for "a number minus 3".\lines{1}

\part[1] %Question 1
Write an algebraic expression for " a number plus 5".\lines{1}



Solutions

\textbf{[1]} $x-3$  % Solution to Question 2 <----------------- Solution to Question 2 has moved above it.

\textbf{[2]} $x+5$  % Solution to Question 1



\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: usually solutions (using \begin{solution} ... \end{solution}) are entered with the questions (share counter) and are usually hidden ([answers] or \printanswers).  See pages 54 through 80 of the manual.

Comment: @John Kormylo But it doesn't do what I want. I want the questions and solutions on two separate pages. Once I remove the question, i want the solution to be removed too.

Comment: Sorry.  I thought that would be a standard option, but evidently not (I don' use it myself).  You might use the endnotes package.

Comment: All good, I am trying to find a solution where I can pair two pieces of information. I think the post below is on the right track but I don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: It is loosely based on how footnotes are created.

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me that one could use a savebox to collect solutions and preserve the formatting.  However the formatting was not appropriate for a separate list.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newcommand{\mysolution}[1]{\global\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\unvbox\mybox\medskip
  \begin{solution}#1\end{solution}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
Write an algebraic expression for "a number minus 3".
\mysolution{$x-3$}

\question
Write an algebraic expression for " a number plus 5".
\mysolution{\blindtext}
\end{questions}

\begin{flushleft}
Solutions

\unvbox\mybox% box is now empty
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

---

My next attempt tried to emulate the question formatting.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newcommand{\mysolution}[1]{\global\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\unvbox\mybox\medskip
  \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\questionlabel}\hskip\labelsep
  \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1}\par}}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
Write an algebraic expression for "a number minus 3".
\mysolution{$x-3$}

\question
Write an algebraic expression for " a number plus 5".
\mysolution{\blindtext}
\end{questions}

\begin{flushleft}
Solutions

\unvbox\mybox% box is now empty
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

---

This version automatically prints the solution at the end of each layer.  I only implemented questions and parts, but extending it is straightforward.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysolution}[1]{\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\unvbox\mybox\medskip
  \leftskip=\@totalleftmargin
  \noindent\llap{\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\mylabel}\hskip\labelsep}%
  #1\par}}

\newcommand{\printmybox}{\ifprintanswers
  \ifvoid\mybox
  \else
    \uplevel{\textbf{Solutions}}\par
    \unvbox\mybox
  \fi
\fi}

\newcommand{\emptybox}{\setbox\mybox=\copy\voidb@x}
\makeatother

% modify environments
\xapptocmd{\questions}{\emptybox
  \let\mylabel=\questionlabel}{}{appto questions failed}
\xpretocmd{\endquestions}{\printmybox}{}{preto endquestions failed}

\xapptocmd{\parts}{\emptybox
  \let\mylabel=\partlabel}{}{appto parts failed}
\xpretocmd{\endparts}{\printmybox}{}{preto endparts failed}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
Write an algebraic expression for "a number minus 3".
\mysolution{$x-3$}

\question
Write an algebraic expression for " a number plus 5".
\mysolution{\blindtext}

\question
\begin{parts}
\part
Write an algebraic expression for "a number minus 3".
\mysolution{$x-3$}

\part
Write an algebraic expression for " a number plus 5".
\mysolution{\blindtext}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

---

This version reproduces the question labels in their entirety.  The purpose of the `\prelabel` was to add `3.` in front of `(a)`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newsavebox{\prelabel}% previous label

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysolution}[1]{\global\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\unvbox\mybox\medskip
  \leftskip=\@totalleftmargin
  \noindent\llap{\box\prelabel\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\mylabel}\hskip\labelsep}%
  #1\par}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\printmybox}{\ifprintanswers
  \ifvoid\mybox
  \else
    \fullwidth{\textbf{Solutions}}\par
    \unvbox\mybox
  \fi
\fi}

\newcommand{\newprelabel}{\setbox\prelabel=\hbox{% store current level label
  \box\prelabel\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\mylabel}\hskip\labelsep}}

% modify environments
\xapptocmd{\questions}{\let\mylabel=\questionlabel}{}{appto questions failed}

\xpretocmd{\parts}{\newprelabel}{}{preto parts failed}
\xapptocmd{\parts}{\let\mylabel=\partlabel}{}{appto parts failed}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
Write an algebraic expression for ``a number minus 3''.
\mysolution{$x-3$}

\question
Write a paragraph in Latin.
\mysolution{\blindtext}

\question
\begin{parts}
\part
Write an algebraic expression for ``a number plus 5''.
\mysolution{$x+5$}

\part
Write a paragraph in Latin.
\mysolution{\blindtext}
\end{parts}

\printmybox
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it doable under exam class?

Comment: @AlanJones At first glimpse I thought about a mechanism like the table of contents, i.e., writing an external text file containing entries of pattern `\entry{<number of question>}{<number of part>}{<number of subpart>}{<number of subsubpart>}{Text that forms the answer}` and a command which evaluates these entries within another `questions`-environment and hereby by means of the numbers "decides" whether to insert/end another `parts`/`subparts`/`subsuparts`-environment and whether solutions to some answers were omitted.  But it seems you can have only one `questions`-environment per document.

Comment: @AlanJones So I think it is doable under the exam-class, but will be a lot of work as patching some of the things of the exam-class is required while the documentation of the implementation of the exam-class in my opinion is a nightmare.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I have to look at other packages that can pair up two blocks of information.

Comment: @AlanJones Besides this in the exam-class the naming of internal data-structures which only exist during the LaTeX-run/during compilation, e.g., the naming of internal referencing labels, is not strictly separated from the printing of numbering in the resulting output-file. This can cause problems like weird messages about multiply defined labels when having more than one `question`-environment.

Comment: @UlrichDiez so what do you suggest?

Comment: @AlanJones Currently I don't see an ideal solution. ;-(  I just looked at the .cls-file underlying the exam-class. Within that file only a few modifications would be sufficient for making several `question`-environments possible. But modifying a .cls-file is not good practice. Usually you have the .cls-file loaded and afterwards have some code executed for redefining the things to be patched. But the definition-text of the macros that would need patching is huge, thus the patches would be huge amounts of code although only a few tokens would be changed/added...

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thanks for your time/effort. I am going to look deep in the web to find a solution. If i find one, ill post the answer here.

Comment: @John Kormylo, I am trying to understand your last edit. Can you briefly explain it so that way I know what's going on. I am not that good at creating complicated macros.

Comment: There is a lot going on.  I switched from \global to local \setbox so that each layer (question, part, etc.) has different contents.  \leftskip=\@totalleftmargin is SOP for lists, with the label installed using \llap (overlapping the left margin/indentation).  xpatch modifies the question and part environments, and in particular uses the label format appropriate to that layer.

Comment: I think this is beyond what I normally know about LaTeX. How do I go about placing an indent to all solutions or \hspace? ```\noindent\llap{\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\mylabel}\hskip\labelsep}``` I noticed when i change [r] to [l] it changes the question numbers.

Comment: If you want the solutions to be indented relative to the questions, you can either add another layer or just use `\setlength{\leftskip}{\dimexpr \@totalleftmargin+\leftmargin}` since `\leftmargin=\labelwidth+\labelsep`.  I learned most of this by digging through source2e (CTAN).